# Translating jQuery to Vanilla JS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was watching a tutorial that used jQuery and wanted to turn it into JS, but my code is broken - was hoping someone could help me with this:

Tutorial JS:

```
$(function() {
    var btn = $('button');
    var progressBar = $('.progressbar');

    btn.click(function() {
        progressBar.find('li.active').next().addClass('active');
    })
})
```

Taken from URL:http://www.kodhus.com/kodity/codify/kod/mGXAtb

Here is my failed attempt at rewriting the jQuery using JavaScript DOM:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON');
var progBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar');

function clickMe1() {
    var elm = progBar.querySelectorAll("li");
    var emlClass = elm.querySelector(".active");
    return emlClass.nextElementSibling.addClass('active');
}

btn1.addEventListener("click", clickMe1, false);
```

where did I go wrong?

Comment: Thank you, this really clarifies the .find() in the jQuery above. I didn't realize it was it was an array issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/159/)**.

Your code will work after several changes check the notes below :

1. You've missed `addClass()` there it's a jQuery function, for vanilla JS use `.classList.add()` instead:

   ```
   return emlClass.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
   ```
2. `querySelectorAll();` will return a list of nodes you have to loop through them and add class, use :

   ```
   var emlClass = progBar.querySelectorAll("li.active");
   ```

   Instead of :

   ```
   var elm = progBar.querySelectorAll("li");
   var emlClass = elm.querySelector(".active");
   ```

   Then loop and add `active` class:

   ```
   for(var i=0;i<emlClass.length;i++){
       emlClass[i].nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
   }
   ```
3. `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByClassName()` will also returns a list of nodes with given name, you have to specify which one you want to pick (selecting the first in my example) :

   ```
   var btn1 = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[0];
   var progBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar')[0];
   ```

Hope this helps.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON')[0];
var progBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar')[0];

function clickMe1() {
  var emlClass = progBar.querySelectorAll("li.active");
  
  for(var i=0;i<emlClass.length;i++){
    emlClass[i].nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
  }
}

btn1.addEventListener("click", clickMe1, false);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2</li>
    <li>Step 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Next step</button>
```

Comment: Thank you all, this really clarifies the .find() in the jQuery above. I didn't realize it was it was an array issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.querySelectorAll("li")` will return an array (or an array-like object) with one or more <li> tags. So you need to either:

- loop through every <li> in that list and do the rest,
- or just take the first item from that list if you don't want to worry about there being more than one li in the page,
- or use `.querySelector` (not `.querySelectorAll`) to just take the first <li> for you.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Care to explain please more please.

Comment: `progBar.querySelectorAll("li")` will return an array with one or more <li> tags. So you need to either loop through every <li> in that list and do the rest, _or_ just take the first item from that list if you don't want to worry about there being more than one li in the page, _or_ use `.querySelector` (not `.querySelectorAll`) to just take the first <li> for you.

Comment: And you'd need to do that for each class selector.

Comment: Also, you're finding "li .active" rather than "li.active", which would find different elements. And you can use `.querSelectorAll("li.active")` instead of doing 2 separate queries.

Comment: The answer itself focussed on the actual problem that was making your code not run, so sorry for the ton of stuff added in the comments.

Comment: Please not in comments but edit you answer (note, i'm not the guy who ask ).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: Yeah, fair enough. Though only that first comment clarified the answer. The rest are just pointers as to what the OP could do.